# How to display information from windows store App

Tags: c++, windows-store-apps

I want to continously show the messages from my app,dont want to wait for the user to close the message like the below code does:

```
     using namespace Windows::UI::Popups;
     MessageDialog^ msg = ref new MessageDialog("your message");
     msg->ShowAsync();
```

instead of this i want something which could continuosly write to my App window.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1). You can handle, when to open or when to close.